# How to perform type conversion with in sql query ? OR How to return values based on datatype in DB?

Tags: php, mysql, yii, xampp

I am using Yii framework ,

```
$user = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->select('*')
->from('user_entraders')
->where('user_id=:id') //where($condition, $params)  
->bindValue(":id", 1, PDO::PARAM_INT)
->queryRow();

   **SCHEMA OF TABLE**
-------------------------
user_id     |    int(11)    
-------------------------   
firstname   |   varchar(200)
-------------------------   
lastname    |   varchar(100)
-------------------------   
username    |   varchar(250)
-------------------------   
password    |   varchar(250)
-------------------------
email       |   varchar(100)
-------------------------
```

Here data type of all the field is string.
Is there any way to perform type conversion within query ?

Comment: will you please post your schema create statement because it seems column `user_id` is integer and primary key.

Comment: @gvgvgvijayan schema is added

Comment: I didn't really understand the problem, can you rephrase it? What's the output you're expecting and what are you actually getting?